# HTML tags not working with Content-Type: application/json

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

HTML tags are displaying on browser when I use `header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");`

When I use bellow table code in file, it is displaying same code on browser, it should display just inner content. On browser table is displaying like this.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

it should display

```
Name1  Name2  Name3
```

It is my complete code

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "angular");

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM user");

    $outp = "";
    while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        if ($outp != "") { $outp .= ","; }
        $outp .= '{"id":"'  . $rs["id"] . '",';
        $outp .= '"name":"'   . $rs["name"]        . '",';
        $outp .= '"father":"'. $rs["father"]     . '"}';
        $outp .= '"designation":"'. $rs["designation"]     . '"}'; 
    }
    $outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
    $conn->close();

    echo($outp);
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why you use `application/json`? You should use  `text/html`

Comment: Your output must be 100% JSON, you can't have trailing HTML.

Comment: But you return an html page. That do not work.

Comment: Basically I want to display my json values in HTML, How can I display my json in html

Comment: You appear to be building an html view. You don't need to return json, just return text/html and use a templating engine in php(or just plain php loops) to build the html and return that

Comment: Just a simple question, If I don't use application/json, will my json work? or what will be happen If don't use application/json ?

Comment: Why you need table in your JSON? JSON don't have any visualization, nor markup valid in HTML, table will break your JSON. Use `text/html` to display HTML content (browser may apply specific styles than). You can output JSON string in any content type.